# LC-3 Iterating Through Memory Block

Tags: arrays, memory, assembly, ascii, lc3

I have a basic loop that asks the user to input a value, which then is printed to the screen. The program stops looping when the user hits enter. I also want to save the other inputs into a memory block for later use. From my simple understanding, I think I'm only storing the values in the first memory slot, and I overwrite that memory slot each time the user enters a value. How do I iterate through the memory block?

Thanks

```
.ORIG x3000

        LEA R0, memSpace
LOOP    GETC
        ADD R3, R0, #-13
        BRz DONE
        OUT
        STR R2, R0, #0
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        ADD R1, R1, #-1
        BRnzp LOOP
        memSpace .BLKW 30
        LEA R3, memSpace
        PUTS
DONE    HALT

.END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so we have a few problems here...

1. `memSpace .BLKW 30` should be *after* `HALT` to avoid overwriting the instruction.
2. `GETC` copies the character into `R0`, so you lose the `memSpace` register. Put the array pointer in `R2` instead; you are already incrementing `R2`, as needed.
3. Now, you need to `STR R0, R2, #0`.
4. `ADD R1, R1, #-1` does nothing useful.
5. 13 is the ASCII code for carriage return; you probably want to change that to 10 for line feed.

There are a few other points worth addressing. Instead of using `BRnzp LOOP`, unconditionally branch with `BR LOOP`. Also, the `LEA` and `PUTS` instructions between the branch and halt are unreachable; I assume that you put them there for debug purposes. While you may have meant to write the contents of memSpace to the console display, `PUTS` will not necessarily do so. It will terminate on a space (or, perhaps, never). In any case, you would need `LEA R0, memSpace1` before `PUTS`.

**Fixed version:**

```
.ORIG x3000

        LEA R2, memSpace
LOOP    GETC
        ADD R3, R0, #-10
        BRz DONE
        OUT
        STR R0, R2, #0
        ADD R2, R2, #1
        BRnzp LOOP
DONE    HALT

memSpace .BLKW 30

.END
```